# OpenCart. Вывод только на главную страницу

Tags: cms, opencart, html, интернет-магазин, tpl

Здравствуйте. Делаю интернет-магазин. Нужно на главной странице разместить табличку, но когда пишу в файлы шаблонов в папке common, это отображается на всех страницах. Не понимаю куда написать, чтобы только на главной выводилось. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

common/home.tpl